# send post request to copy file and get progress response

Tags: php, jquery

am sending a post request to copy a file using the below code

```
 $.ajax({
     url:filename,
     type: 'post',
     dataType: 'html',
     data: {"data":someData}, 
     success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       alert(data);
     },
     error:function(err){
      console.log(err);
     }
   });
```

this below function copies file and gives me the progress

```
function copyfiles($filename,$filesize){
    $remote = fopen('../filestorage/'.$filename, 'r');
    $local = fopen('../uploads/'.$filename, 'w');
    $read_bytes = 0;
    while(!feof($remote)) {
      $buffer = fread($remote, 2048);
      fwrite($local, $buffer);
      $read_bytes += 2048;
      $progress = min(100, 100 * $read_bytes / $filesize);
  echo json_encode(array("progress"=>$progress));
    }
   fclose($remote);
   fclose($local);
}
```

but what i get is one response like below

```
        {"progress":16.956449743335}{"progress":33.91289948667} 
         {"progress":50.869349230005}{"progress":67.82579897334}
         {"progress":84.782248716675}{"progress":100}
```

i want to get one by one and then show the progress of how much it is copied.
  Please suggest how can i do it.

Comment: yes . ok can u please tell me how can i go about it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of achieving this would be to have two services (or php pages etc). One service (s1) could be the one you already have which accepts a request and starts copying. The other service (s2) could be responding with the status for each file that is being copied. In order for this to work you need to take the following into account

1. service s1 should respond immediately with an id or filename that started copying
2. while copying the progress should be kept in a map where the key of the file map to progress values (remember the user may need to copy multiple files)
3. the client should constantly call service s2 to get progress values, passing as parameter the file key
4. service s2 should look into that map and respond with the progress of the requested file key

Services and maps can easily work/be stored in conjunction with the http session of the client in order to serve accurately multiple clients. Other methods of storing could be chosen, i think http session is the most straightforward and proper for this case.

**EDIT**

This is a demo app in php where a service s1 is writing in http session and service s2 is reading from it. Your code is left within commented out to show where about you could place the new code.

**HTML/JS**

```html
<body>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="file" value="file1" />file1
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" name="file" value="file2" />file2
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" name="file" value="file3" />file3
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" name="file" value="file4" />file4
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="copy files" />
            <br/><br/>
            <div class="output"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script>
            var progressInterval;
            $('input[type=button]').on('click',function(){
                var filename = $('input:checked').val();
                if(!filename)return;
                $.ajax({
                    url:'service-copy-file.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {"filename":filename},
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        if(progressInterval) {
                            clearInterval(progressInterval);
                        }
                    },
                    error:function(err){
                        console.log(err);
                        if(progressInterval) {
                            clearInterval(progressInterval);
                        }
                    }
                });

                progressInterval = setInterval(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'service-progress.php',
                        type: 'get',
                        data: {"filename":filename},
                        dataType:'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $('.output').text((parseInt(data.progress))+"%");
                        },
                        error:function(err){
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    });

                }, 1000);

            });



        </script>
    </body>
```

**service s1**

```php
<?php

copyfiles($_POST['filename'], null);

function copyfiless($filename, $filesize) {
    echo json_encode('copying ' . $filename);
}

function copyfiles($filename, $filesize) {
    // $remote = fopen('../filestorage/'.$filename, 'r');
    // $local = fopen('../uploads/'.$filename, 'w');
    // $read_bytes = 0;
    //emulate copying of a file for 10secs
    $fileKey = $filename;
    $progress = 0;

    $_SESSION[$fileKey] = $progress;
    // while(!feof($remote)) {
    while ($progress < 100) {
        session_start();
        //  $buffer = fread($remote, 2048);
        //  fwrite($local, $buffer);
        //  $read_bytes += 2048;
        //  $progress = min(100, 100 * $read_bytes / $filesize);
        //  echo json_encode(array("progress"=>$progress));

        sleep(2); //emulate copying
        $progress+=10;
        $_SESSION[$fileKey] = $progress;
        session_write_close();
    }
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION[$fileKey]); //completed copy
    // fclose($remote);
    // fclose($local);
}

?>
```

**service s2**

```php
<?php

session_start();

getProgress($_GET['filename']);

function getProgress($filename) {
    if (isset($_SESSION[$filename])) {
        echo json_encode(array("progress" => $_SESSION[$filename]));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("progress" => -1));
        // echo json_encode('could not find file:'.$filename);
    }
}

?>
```

This will give real time progress of your file being copied. However if you want to get a response from the server without having to poll for it from the client, then you need to use HTTP server push which needs a bit more effort to achive.

Comment: @melc thanks for the reply. I tried your way where client is calling service s1 to copy. also this service calls a method in service s2 to set the progress values. Once i send a req to copy the file, i also send a request to service s2 to get progress response, but what am getting is empty results. can you let me know if i missed anything

Comment: @nyfer s1 should store progress values in an array with key the filename or something unique and value an array with progress values or just last progress value. Then store the array in user's session, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp . No need to request s2 from s1. When the client calls s2 with filename key returned from s1, s2 should check the session and return progress.I'll try to post some code within the day if you really need it.

Comment: @melc thanks. check this link to see how i have done it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605009/not-able-to-get-file-copying-progress

Comment: @melc yes melc can you post it , i really need it. am trying to make it work , but somehow it doesnt work. also can we get the progress real time instead of storing in session and then retrieving it?

Comment: @nyfer edited the answer with a demo implementation, hope it helps you out.

Comment: @melc thanks melc a lot!! it worked. just wanted to know. if several users copy multiple files , will it create any problems

Comment: @nyfer there will be no problem, your server can serve each user at the same time and it will be using a separate http session for each one of them. In order to support multiple files you can either tweak the code a bit and send multiple file names for sequential copy at the server, or to copy them in parallel you can leave it as is and simply make multiple client requests for each file selected (you can check this if you run the demo in multiple tabs of the same browser (single user and session) and if you open multiple browsers you will have multiple users/sessions) .

Comment: @melc hi melc i tried to get progress of all the files being copied, but am getting the progress as -1 
session_start();
foreach($qryStr as $value) {
  $success = 1;
  $src = $value;
  $dest = "../home/tmp";
  
  $cmd = 'scp '.$src.' '.$dest.'';
  sleep(1);
  $progress+=$offset;
  $_SESSION[$timestamp] = $progress;
  var_dump($_SESSION[$timestamp]);
  $result = shell_exec($cmd);
  }

Comment: @melc the session data is null when i try to access it in service-progress. any problem in the script. $value is location of each file

Answer (score 1):

The only time I did that was 4 years ago. Don't know if it will help you, but that was my system :

1. When doing a long treatment (not only a file transfer) the PHP used to do it have to store process into a file (or mysql db...) don't forget to close the file (if you choose a file) for reading rights!
2. during this, a callback (in `ajax` now, but it was an automatic refresh for me) call a PHP function that return the current process value reading the file (or the db)

Hop it will help!