# Not able to get file copying progress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Am trying to get progress of file being copied

initially i send a request to copy the file using the below code. once the file is created. i send a response success=1 and start the copying process and also call **getProgress**

```
   $.ajax({
     url:'copyFile.php',
     type: 'post',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {'data':someData}, 
     success: function(data) {
       if(data.success){
         progressIndex=setInterval(getProgress, 1000 );
       }
     },
     error:function(err){
      console.log(err);
     }
   });


    function getProgress(){
    $.ajax({
     url:'FileUploadProgress.php',
     type: 'post',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {'progress':'1'}, 
     success: function(data) {
       if(!data.success){
        clearTimeout(progressIndex);
       }
     },
     error:function(err){
      console.log(err);
     }
   });
}
```

**FileUploadProgress.php**

```
class FileUploadProgress{
   private $filename;
   private $progress;

 public function setfileProgress($filename,$progress){
    $this->filename=$filename;
  $this->progress=$progress;
  }

function returnProgress(){
   if(empty($this->filename) || empty($this->progress)){
     echo json_encode(array('success'=>'0'));
   }else{
echo json_encode(array('success'=>1,'filename'=>$this->filename,'progress'=>$this- 
>progress));
}
}

}
  $fileuploadprogress=new FileUploadProgress;
  if($_POST['progress']){

      $fileuploadprogress->returnProgress();
 }
```

while copying am getting the progress and calling the function **setfileProgress** 
to set the progress. Also in client side i have requested for progress , but wat am getting is success=0 and $this->progress is empty
  Am i missing anything in my code. Please let me know

Comment: This is not an easy job to handle with php alone.

You must understand that after each execution everything is lost. So on each ajax call a new FileUploadProgress instance is created, witch doesn't have access to the previous instance properties, think of it as like a new program is started on each ajax call.

Comment: ok yes! so can i create the instance before copying and send it as response back to client. and then pass that instance to get the progress?

Comment: @PoelincaDorin or may be i can use singleton pattern to check if only one instance is created?

Comment: Singleton pattern would work for the current request only as i've mentioned before, you need a background service to query, or as Nagh mentioned use the Session witch is persistent among requests.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make way to query some datasource to get your progress status.
Like dumping progress status in some DB table or file, etc..

However PHP have some hacks, that works in some enviroment.
Check following docs: [Session Upload Progress](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php).